# Android HttpURLConnection PUT to Amazon AWS S3 403 error

Tags: java, android, amazon-s3, httpurlconnection, put

Uploading a file to Amazon S3 using presigned URL which has Signature, Expiration and AccessKey, using the following code I'm able to upload the file using normal java code but same code in Android gives me 403 error.  Presigned URL is generate using Amazon SDK

I have read http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html 
and http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html but not able to figure out what header param should i use, I guess in android it is setting headers in request which server rejects

```
    HttpURLConnection connection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestMethod("PUT"); 
    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
    out.write("This text uploaded as object.");
    out.close();
    int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
```

Exception: 403; Signature don't match :-o

Has anyone come across this issue?
Or more details into which Header-parameters are added behind the scenes from android library?

Comment: have u got any solution for this??@Mayank

Comment: I have same issue, did you get any solution?

Answer (score 5):

please set your content type like this:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type"," ");
```

because the default for HttpsUrlConnection Automatically generates content type as:

```
"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

This will cause signature mismatch.

Answer (score 2):

So after some trial/error/search found out the issue:

While creating a presigned URL is it important to specify Content-Type (based on your data) or else you will keep getting 403 Signature don't match, the contentType that you specify here should be mentioned in HttpURLConnection  connection object

```
    string s3url = s3Client.GetPreSignedURL(new GetPreSignedUrlRequest()
                   .WithBucketName(bucketName)
                   .WithKey(keyName)
                   .WithContentType("application/octet-stream") // IMPORTANT
                   .WithVerb(HttpVerb.PUT)
                   .WithExpires(<YOUR EXPIRATION TIME>);
```

Inside your connection..add this to the code in question after ("PUT")

```
    connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(< YOUR DATA.LENGTH ?>);        
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/octet-stream");
```

Check this [bug](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=435180), latest SDK should let you set Content-Type

Comment: No... This won't work for me...
I am able to upload using JAVA client running from mac os.
However with same url I am getting 403 error.
It mean different is about Android environment Vs mac os.

Answer (score 1):

The way to generate the URL:

```
private static URL generateRUL(String objectKey, String ACCESS_KEY, String SECRET_KEY, String BUCKET_NAME) {
    AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY));
    URL url = null;

    try {
        GeneratePresignedUrlRequest request  = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(BUCKET_NAME, objectKey);
        request.setMethod(com.amazonaws.HttpMethod.PUT);
        request.setExpiration(new Date( System.currentTimeMillis() + (60 * 60 * 1000)));

        // Very important ! It won't work without adding this! 
        // And request.addRequestParameter("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream") won't work neither
        request.setContentType("application/octet-stream");

        url = s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(request ); 
    } catch (AmazonServiceException exception) { 
    } catch (AmazonClientException ace) { }

    return url;
}
```

The way to upload the file:

```
public int upload(byte[] fileBytes, URL url) {
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream"); // Very important ! It won't work without adding this!
    OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream();

    InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileBytes);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int length;
    while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    output.flush();

    return connection.getResponseCode();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the [AWS SDK for Android](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforandroid/)? That has the correct APIs and I suspect it will be easier to upload to S3 using that, and more secure for that matter. I believe they have tutorials, code samples, and demos there as well.

There is also an [API for S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/) and other classes you may need. A [PutObjectRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.html) is what will help you upload the file from the phone client and can be useful in your case.

Comment: To limit the size of App I'm avoiding use of SDK on the device and I don't want to use the SDK for that one operation.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.  Here's the reason why I faced it:

> A pre-signed URL gives you access to the object identified in the URL,
>   provided that the creator of the pre-signed URL has permissions to
>   access that object. That is, if you receive a pre-signed URL to upload
>   an object, you can upload the object o**nly if the creator of the
>   pre-signed URL has the necessary permissions to upload that object**.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html

Once I gave my lambda function PutObject permissions on that s3 bucket then it worked!